# The method or operation is not implemented exception in Script Notify for webview in windows runtime apps c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-10-universal, windows-8.1-universal

This below code is working in windows 8, when coming to windows 8.1 universal apps it is showing error method not implemented when assign urls to  wv1.AllowedScriptNotifyUris..

XAML Code:

```
<WebView Name="wv1" ScriptNotify="wv1_ScriptNotify_1" LoadCompleted="wv1_LoadCompleted_1"/>
```

Cs Code:

```
private async void BrowserPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    wv1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.google.com/search?q=" + "Devi", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));            
}
private void wv1_LoadCompleted_1(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
{      
    var absolutepath = e.Uri.Host.ToString() + e.Uri.AbsolutePath.ToString().Substring(0, e.Uri.AbsolutePath.ToString().LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    allowedUris.Add(new Uri(e.Uri.ToString()));
    wv1.AllowedScriptNotifyUris = allowedUris;//error coming in this line
    string[] args = { "this.newfunc_eventHandler=function(e){e.cancelBubble = true;var  dataValue= document.selection.createRange().htmlText.toString();window.external.notify(dataValue);}" };
    wv1.InvokeScript("eval", args);//error also in this line
    string[] arg = { "document.body.addEventListener('copy',newfunc_eventHandler,true);" };
    wv1.InvokeScript("eval", arg);//error also in this line                                    
}
```

In windows 8 apps this code is used for enable script when copy button click in webview page. But when coming to windows 8.1 Universal apps while assign url and script it returns method not implemented error.please help to solve this problem...

Comment: Can you include the exception message and stack please

Comment: @Brody The method or operation is not implemented.

Comment: Then perhaps wv1 is out of scope. Can you use the sender object instead?

Comment: @Brody for what parpus..

Answer (score 0):

See the remarks in the [AllowedScriptNotifyUri docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.allowedscriptnotifyuris.aspx)

Windows 8.1
AllowedScriptNotifyUris is not supported in apps compiled for Windows 8.1. To enable an external web page to fire the ScriptNotify event when calling window.external.notify, you must include the page's URI in the ApplicationContentUriRules section of the app manifest. (You can do this in Visual Studio on the Content URIs tab of the Package.appxmanifest designer.) The URIs in this list must use HTTPS, and may contain subdomain wildcards (for example, https://*.microsoft.com) but they cannot contain domain wildcards (for example, https://*.com and https://*.*). The manifest requirement does not apply to content that originates from the app package, uses an ms-local-stream:// URI, or is loaded using NavigateToString.

Comment: but every time we have to chnage ApplicationContentUriRules, for different urls..